# DispatchGroup Order of Operation

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Hello i am trying to get result based on a result from another api.The getLatest function is going to get the latest object and will return the number then i want to generate a list of urls with the latest number and then sequentially get the data in the function getXKCDData.How can i achieve this.The dispatchgroup i have on there works sometimes but doesnt work all the time because generateUrlList is called before getting the latest number and it generate the wrong url.Which causes *The operation couldn’t be completed. (XKCD_Comics.NetworkError error 1.*) error.How can i achieve this.

```
final class NetworkManager {
    
    public static var shared = NetworkManager()
    
    private let sessions = URLSession.shared
        
    private func generateUrlList(latestXKCD: Int) -> [String] {
        print("Here at generateUrlList")
        var urls = [String]()
        for i in latestXKCD-100...latestXKCD{
            let xkcd_url = "https://xkcd.com/\(i)/info.0.json"
            urls.append(xkcd_url)
        }
        return urls
    }
    
    private func getLatest(completion: @escaping(Int) -> ()){
        print("Here at get latest")
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://xkcd.com/info.0.json") else { return }
        let task = sessions.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let jsonData = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(Comics.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(response.num)
                
            }catch {
                completion(0)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
    
    public func getXKCDData(completion: @escaping(Result<Comics,NetworkError>) -> Void){
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var latestID = 0
        group.enter()
        self.getLatest { (result) in
            latestID = result
            group.leave()
            
        }
    
        let urlList = generateUrlList(latestXKCD: latestID)
        print(urlList)
        print("Here at getXKCDData")
        
        for url in urlList {
            group.enter()
            guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
                completion(.failure(.InvalidURL))
                return
            }
            
            let task = sessions.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let jsonData = data else {
                    completion(.failure(.NoDataAvailable))
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let response = try decoder.decode(Comics.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(response))
                    group.leave()
                    
                }catch {
                    completion(.failure(.CanNotProcessData))
                    
                }
                
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Well it all depends on what you mean by "sequentially" get the data.

Comment: so sequentially meaning 1.call the function sequentially getLatest - > generateUrlList -> then get the data from the list
2. the url  in the list are in sequence like [https://xkcd.com/2300/info.0.json, https://xkcd.com/2301/info.0.json] so call them in order

Comment: you can use `wait` to force each networking call to wait for the previous ones to finish, but is that something you really want to do? it's better just to associate the index number with the result.

Comment: What do you mean by associate the index number with the result.Thanks

Comment: Look at it this way. The URLs get their responses in no order. You are saying `success(response)`. So the callback provides the response but does not say which url it is the response to!

Comment: Unrelated but be aware that you are *leaving* the group at three(!) places without informing the group.

Comment: @vadian how can i make it cleaner?

Comment: Call `defer {group.leave()}` right at the beginning of the closure. And call `group.enter()` **after** validating the URL.